# Return table values in php

Tags: php, for-loop, return

I have this code:

```
public function getYears()
{

     for($yearNum = 1; $yearNum <= 12; $yearNum++){
         $year[]=$this->year;
        echo $year[$yearNum]=$yearNum;
    }
    return $yearNum;
}
```

I have this error:
PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

How can i return this 12 numbers?

Comment: heh it is month but i write years

Comment: i do that: `code`public function getMonths()
    {
        
         for($monthNum = 1; $monthNum <= 12; $monthNum++){
            echo $month[$monthNum]=$monthNum;
        }
        return [$month];
    }`code`

Comment: sorry i have now "0" in my first returned value anyone know howm to resolve this? i need only 12 numbers(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) without 0

Comment: what is $this->year?

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments:

> i need only 12 numbers(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) without 0

You can get 12 numbers by using this:

```
public function getYears()
{
    for($yearNum = 1; $yearNum <= 12; $yearNum++){
        //$year[] = $yearNum;
        $year[] = $yearNum;
        //echo $year[$yearNum]=$yearNum;
    }
    return $year;
}

// calling function
$result = $this->getYears();
//echo "<pre>";
$numbers = implode(",", $result);
echo $numbers; //1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
```